# Alternative option for passing profiles details for spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot

When we try to run the jar file from the command prompt, we use "-Dspring.profiles.active=common,localhost".

But for >2.2 version we need to use "-Dspring-boot.run.profiles". What is the alternative option for jvm argument to run.

java -jar test.jar --spring.config.location=test.properties -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=localhost

Comment: Note: Jar file will be running in nginx server.

Comment: You should still use `--spring.profiles.active` as an argument the `spring-boot.run.profiles` is for use with the maven plugin afaik.

Comment: But its not working. Still app is blowing stating could not resolve placeholders. That's because app is not picking up the profiles correctly

Comment: Then you aren't passing it correctly or haven't included the proper files. As stated use it as a program argument NOT as a -D argument.